# How to check multiple R columns for a value?

Tags: r, regex, filter, dplyr, apply

I have an R dataframe with hundreds of columns which can contain a number. The columns all follow a naming scheme like:

```
1_parameter, 2_parameter, 3_parameter, ...
```

I want to filter for the rows where any of the above mentioned columns contains, lets say the number 97. How can I do this, instead of using an explicit filter like the dplyr command given below, where I have to write every single column explicitly?:

```
filter(1_parameter==97 | 2_parameter==97 | ...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (assuming your data is named `df`)

```
# get the column names that follow this pattern
cols = grepl("[0-9]+_parameter", names(df))
# see if any of those columns have a 97
any(df[cols] == 97)
```

A base R way to filter for rows that have a 97 in any of those columns is this:

```
df[rowSums(df[cols] == 97) > 0, ]
```

Comment: Ok this does what I asked for, sorry I need to rephrase: How would I filter for the rows, where any row contains a 97? I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
     filter_at(vars(ends_with("_parameter")), any_vars(. == 97))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of `dplyr`, the option would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
 df %>%
    filter(across(ends_with('parameter'), ~ . == 97) %>% reduce(`|`))
```